# Drupal 8 : Render a field collection item in a Twig template

Tags: theming, 8, entities

In Drupal 8, I have a content type which use Field Collection Module like that :

- `field_body` (FieldCollection, repeatable)

  - `field_image_alignment`(Boolean)
  - `field_picture` (Image)
  - `field_free_text` (Long Text)

I want to theme this fields.
I overrided the field template with a file named `field--node--field-body--news.html` (news is the content type that contains theses fields.).

Default template is this :

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And my template overrided is like that :

```
{% for item in items %}
  {% if item.content['#field_collection_item'].field_image_alignment.value == 1 %}
    {{ dump(item.content['#field_collection_item'].field_picture) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I render "child" fields `field_pictures`, `field_free_text` ?
I used `item.content['#field_collection_item'].field_image_alignment.value`to access to the plain value but I would like to have the rendered view.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just started learning Drupal and encountered the same issue.
I solved it by creating custom field formatter:

```
public function viewElements(FieldItemListInterface $items, $langcode)
{
  $elements = array();
  foreach ($items as $delta => $item)
    if ($item->value !== NULL)
    {
      $builder    = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('field_collection_item');
      $elements[] = $builder->build($builder->view($item->getFieldCollectionItem()));
    }
  return $elements;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this module for Nice Table format Look
Link: https://www.drupal.org/project/reference_table_formatter

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.  I also don't see how this module helps at all with this situation?